# Laravel validation not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have the following method on `POST`:

```
public function postResponseLevel(Request $request, $id){
    if(Auth::guest()){
        return redirect('/auth/login');
    } else {
        try{
            $rules = array(
                'level'    => 'required',

            );
            $this->validate($request, $rules);
            dd($request->all());//THIS LINE IS NOT PRINTING
            $current_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $proj = Project::get($id,$current_user_id);
            if($brief == null){
                throw new Error("Invalid");
            }
            $level = $request->get('response_level');
            $level_fields = explode("_",$level);
            $number_of_experts = $level_fields[0];
            $amount = $level_fields[1];

            $response_level = new ResponseLevel();
            $response_level->add($id, $number_of_experts, $amount);
            print "Go!!";
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It just displays blank page. On refreshing view, it does show session value. Actually it's not redirecting. On removing `$this->validates()` work.

Comment: Does it work when you comment out everything in the else except `dd($request->all());`

Comment: @Daan When I remove `$this->validates()`, it works.

Comment: I am not getting anything in `laravel.log` either

Comment: Ok, just checked, on removing `try catch` blocked it works?

Comment: You write 'validates()' everywhere but in the code, there is no 's' in the call there. Also you require 'level' but use 'response_level' -- is this supposed to work, or are those typos that happened while assembling the example?

Comment: @TomRegner That's typo. In code it's `validate()`. On removing `Exception Block` it's working. Not sure why.